# Route does not display in the browser when clicking url from email

Tags: node.js, routes, email-verification

I have the following **route** upon **email activation**, which is only **loading** and not displaying when I am clicking on the **url from the email**. The **token** is there for surely so no idea what is causing it.

Any idea?

```
app.get('/LimeLINE/activate/:token', (req, res) => {
        try {
            var token = req.params.token;
        } catch (e) {
            log('e', 'app.get(/LimeLINE/activate/:token - e - 160 : ' + e)
            return res.status(403).json({
                message: "No Token"
            });
        }
        if (token) {
            //Decode the token
            jwt.verify(token, "supersecret", (err, decod) => {
                if (err) {
                    res.status(403).json({
                        message: "Expired Token"
                    });
                    log('err', 'app.get(/LimeLINE/activate/:token - err - 173 : ' + err)
                }
                req.decoded = decod;
                user.activateUser(decod, (err) => {
                    if (err) {
                        return sendStatus(500)
                        log('err', 'app.get(/LimeLINE/activate/:token - e - 179 : ' + err)
                    }
                    //console.log(decod.username)
                    try {
                        let sTopHtml = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/components/top.html', 'utf8')
                        let sMainHtml = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/html/index.html', 'utf8')
                        let sBottomHtml = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/components/bottom.html', 'utf8')
                        // replace placeholders
                        sTopHtml = sTopHtml.replace('{{title}}', 'LimeLINE: Get Started')
                        sMainHtml = sMainHtml.replace('{{feedback-message}}', 'feedback-message')
                    } catch (e) {
                        log('e', 'app.get(/LimeLINE/activate/:token - e - 190 : ' + e)
                        return res.sendStatus(500)
                    }
                    return res.send(sTopHtml + sMainHtml + sBottomHtml)
                })

            })
        }
    })
```

Comment: One possible cause for the "hanging" request could be that the callback in the activateUser function is not being called. Can we see that function? Have you tried debugging it?

Comment: exactly, that was it.

Comment: great! could you accept my answer please? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible cause for the "hanging" request could be that the callback in the activateUser function is not being called. Make sure you always call the given callback function, i.e. on success and error.

One advice: use [promises](https://www.promisejs.org/)/[async await](https://medium.com/@Abazhenov/using-async-await-in-express-with-node-8-b8af872c0016) as it helps you to keep your code cleaner and prevent errors like these.